# Can't Install company app windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i have developed company app for windows phone 8 But there is a problem when i want to install the application.

Here is what I did:

1. Registered company account
2. Bought an enterprise certificate from Symantec
3. Exported PFX file with private key
4. Generated Enrollment Token (AETX file) from PFX.
5. Developed application, built with visual studio and get xap file generated (Release, ARM).
6. Sign the xap with XapSignTool
7. Uploaded AETX and signed XAP file on appcenterconsole.
8. Add workplace account for "xxx" company (No message showed, after i add the workplace)
9. Install signed xap
10. Install Failed. It said "Can't install company app. We haven't been able to contact the "xxx" workplace account to make sure you can install this app. Make sure you're connected to a cellular or Wi-Fi network, and we'll try again as soon as we can. Unfortunately, it may take a couple of days before we can make that connection. If you continue to have trouble, contact your company's support person for help

I tried to check the workplace account in Settings-workplace, but i can't find anything.

I have tried to install on 3 devices. Only one device said can't install company app.

Do you have solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: I would double-check that you have properly signed your application according to the instructions by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn168929(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I have signed application with command : XapSignTool.exe sign /f D:\installer\WPCert.pfx /p *** D:\installer\Mordor.xap. And it said "XapSignTool Success : Successfully Signed = D:\installer\Mordor.xap". I have followed this instruction : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681686%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: That does not mean it is correctly signed... with the correct parameters. It sounds like there is either a certificate problem, or a connection problem. And it is not MFP-related.